# Is there any way to create a Span<T> or Memory<T> that refers to the elements of a List<T> in C#?

Tags: c#

Obviously I could do so indirectly (for example by first converting to an array), but I'm aiming to avoid as many copies and allocations as possible.  Ultimately, I want to write a function that returns a `Memory<T>` and constructs that object internally from a `List<T>`.

Comment: Whatever solution you use it won't be linked to the list anymore because the list does not use the same array as it increases in size. You you would at minimum incur one memory copy during the conversion. The only caveat I can see is if you use reflection to get the internal `T[]` the list has, but that reference will only be valid till the list performs a resize operation.

Comment: Resizing is not an issue in my case.  Basically, I'm optimising a generic algorithm that can run on a variety of data structures.  I need a way to efficiently access the values in the data structure, without knowing what the structure is.  There are other ways I can approach this, but `Memory<T>` seems particularly clean (if it works).  (In one particular case, the structure contains List<T> objects internally--hence this question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So long as you promise not to change the value of `.Count` between operations on the memory and never do any action that would cause the internal array of the list to be swapped out the following would work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace SandboxNetStandard
{
    public static class ListAdapter<T>
    {
        private static readonly FieldInfo _arrayField = typeof(List<T>)
            .GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Single(x => x.FieldType == typeof(T[]));

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts
        /// <paramref name="listIPromiseToNotChangeTheCountOfAndNotCauseCapacityToChange"/>
        /// to an <see cref="Memory{T}"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="listIPromiseToNotChangeTheCountOfAndNotCauseCapacityToChange">
        /// The list to convert.
        ///
        /// On each use of the returned memory object the list must have the same value of
        /// <see cref="List{T}.Count"/> as the original passed in value. Also between calls 
        /// you must not do any action that would cause the internal array of the list to
        /// be swapped out with another array.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// A <see cref="Memory{T}"/> that is linked to the passed in list.
        /// </returns>
        public static Memory<T> ToMemory(
            List<T> listIPromiseToNotChangeTheCountOfAndNotCauseCapacityToChange)
        {
            Memory<T> fullArray = (T[]) _arrayField.GetValue(
                    listIPromiseToNotChangeTheCountOfAndNotCauseCapacityToChange);
            return fullArray.Slice(0,
                listIPromiseToNotChangeTheCountOfAndNotCauseCapacityToChange.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I *almost* wouldn't even change that parameter name if I copied this into a project. =p... Seriously

Comment: I think this resizing concern is a little overblown.  Maybe this is my C++ background talking, but I'm OK with a method that returns data that is only valid until the source object is modified (as long as it's properly documented).